# encoding/hex: invalid byte: U+0068 'h' Golang

Tags: arrays, string, go, hex

I'm trying to convert a `string` into a `byte` array containing its hexadecimal values, here is the code I've written:

```
package main

import (
     "encoding/hex"
     "fmt"
     "os"
)

func main() {
     str :="abcdefhijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZ123456789"

     b, err := hex.DecodeString(str)

     if err != nil {
             fmt.Println(err)
             os.Exit(1)
     }

     fmt.Printf("Decoded bytes %v \n ", b)
}
```

Here is the link from Go PlayGround: http://play.golang.org/p/8PMEFTCYSd

But it's giving me the error ***encoding/hex: invalid byte: U+0068 'h' Golang ***. What's the problem here? I want to convert my `string` into `byte` array containing hexadecimal values of each character in the `string`. I want `b[n]` to contain hexadecimal value of `str[n]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I want to convert my `string` into `byte` array containing hexadecimal values of each character in the `string`.

You can simply convert a `string` to a `[]byte` (byte slice, not exactly the same as array!) by using a simple type [conversion](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions):

```
b := []byte(str)
```

And you're done!

If you want to print it as a hexadecimal `string`, you can do that with the [`fmt.Printf()`](http://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Printf) function using both the `string` and the `[]byte`:

```
fmt.Printf("%x", str)
// Or:
fmt.Printf("%x", b)
```

*Tip: you can use the format string `"% x"` to have a space printed between each of the hexadecimal forms of the bytes/characters:*

```
fmt.Printf("% x", str)
```

If you want the result of the hexadecimal form as a `string`, you can use the [`fmt.Sprintf()`](http://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Sprintf) variant:

```
hexst := fmt.Sprintf("%x", str)
// Or:
hexst := fmt.Sprintf("%x", b)
```

Or as an alternative you can use the [`hex.EncodeToString()`](http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/hex/#EncodeToString) function from the `encoding/hex` package:

```
hexst := hex.EncodeToString(b)
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code is trying to decode *from* hex. That string is not hex encoded.

To encode *to* hex try this

```
b := fmt.Sprintf("%x", str)

fmt.Printf("Decoded bytes %v", []byte(b))
```